# Hide Menu on mouse out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used [**this plugin-in**](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/) to create a navigation menu.
Added a new div which is placed left side when on mouse over of it, showing the menu and also on click of text show/hide showing menu.

But having problems like below:

```
 1. Menu is not hiding some times.
 2. Navigating in same menu also it is hiding fractionally and showing.
```

Anybody please suggest me what I am missing to work this perfectly.

Here is the link for [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hhn14qzy/)

Comment: I think that a better approach will be to have the menu stick out just a bit. This way the navigationEdge element would be part of the menu and the onmouseover function would fire as long as you are inside the menu. I will try to create a fiddle to show what I mean...

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnikolopoulos/kLhcdtf2/)

Comment: @siwss_blade Main problem is that when i am on navigation it is repeatedly hiding and showing.

Comment: Have you tried my fiddle? It works just fine for me. Is there anything else on the page that may interfere?

Comment: @swiss_blade I have observed your fiddle. Please mouse over on navigation menu go up & down to observer the problem.

Comment: I do not get that unless I hit the show/hide link before...weird... If I just hover the exposed part of the menu (10px wide), it works just fine...

Comment: @swiss_blade just after click show/hide play in navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating this part of the code:

```
navigationMenu.onmouseout = function() {
        classie.toggle( navigationEdge, 'active' ).delay(100);
        classie.toggle( showLeft, 'active' );
        classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
        };
```

Comment: it is giving TypeError: classie.toggle(...) is undefined

Comment: Oh! yea. this works 100% used jquery mouseenter and mouseleave.
http://jsfiddle.net/hhn14qzy/2/